# Converting Cartesian to Spherical/Polar coordinates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql-10

I am trying to convert Cartesian to spherical coordinates in PostgreSQL.

Illustrations:

- Input: x, y, z
- Output: elevation, azimuth

I tried making a function by a code given in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714604/how-to-convert-spherical-to-cartesian-coordinates-in-postgresql.

I have a similar problem that my function is created by executing the query gives me the error. I have a fundamental knowledge of PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_cart2spr(point_i float, point_j float, 
point_k float)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$ SELECT ST_MakePoint(
SQRT(POWER(i,2) + POWER(j,2) + POWER(k,2)),
DEGREES(ACOS(k / (SQRT(POWER(i,2) + POWER(j,2) + POWER(k,2))))),
DEGREES(ATAN2(j, i)))
FROM (SELECT
 $1 AS i, 
 $2 AS j,
 $3 AS k
) AS f$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

and Query I am trying to run is:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_cart2spr(SELECT ST_x(geom) As X, ST_y(geom) As Y, ST_z(geom) As Z FROM (
    SELECT (St_DumpPoints(geometry)).geom FROM surface_geometry JOIN building ON surface_geometry.id = building.id
                               WHERE geometry IS NOT NULL
                               AND cityobject_id = 95) as foo)
```

Any suggestions to understand where I am doing it wrong?
I guess the error part is in the Function call.

But if I run the subquery without putting it in function, it runs fine — the result of the query separately. (See the [part in picture highlighted in grey)

[image: Query without funtion]

Comment: please provide the error message...

Comment: @JGH Hi, The error stated:  syntax error at or near "`SELECT.`"
LINE 1: `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_cart2spr(SELECT ST_x(geom) As X, ST_y(ge...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the subquery outside of the function call:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_cart2spr(X,Y,Z))
FROM (
 SELECT ST_x(geom) As X, ST_y(geom) As Y, ST_z(geom) As Z 
 FROM (
    SELECT (St_DumpPoints(geometry)).geom 
    FROM surface_geometry 
      JOIN building ON surface_geometry.id = building.id
    WHERE geometry IS NOT NULL
      AND cityobject_id = 95
   ) as foo
 ) as bar;
```

To query the returned geometry, you can again add a subquery:

```
SELECT ST_x(c.geom) As X, ST_y(c.geom) As Y, ST_z(c.geom) As Z 
FROM ( 
    SELECT ST_cart2spr(X,Y,Z) AS geom
    FROM (
     SELECT ST_x(geom) As X, ST_y(geom) As Y, ST_z(geom) As Z 
     FROM (
        SELECT (St_DumpPoints(geometry)).geom 
        FROM surface_geometry 
          JOIN building ON surface_geometry.id = building.id
        WHERE geometry IS NOT NULL
          AND cityobject_id = 95
       ) as a
     ) as b
)as c;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Your suggestion has solved the problem mentioned in my question. Could you please explain to me why one writes `AS bar ` at the end? How can I get the final result similar to the one in the figure above in my question i-e., in separate columns except with Spherical coordinates notations (r, theta, phi)?

Comment: Besides, I have updated the part of the function as ...`DEGREES(ACOS(k / (SQRT(POWER(i,2) + POWER(j,2) + POWER(k,2))))),
DEGREES(ATAN2(j, i)))`...  
to chnage the angle to degrees considering it measures in radian by default.

Comment: sub-queries must have an alias (even if it is not used!). If you remove it, Postgres will complain that it is missing

Comment: Can I have some instructions on pulling out the query's final result in separate columns as `r,` `Theta,` and `Phi.`

Comment: @FRQ sorry, I am not used to this type of coordinates/notations. You may have more answer with a new question

Comment: I meant you don't have to know for that kind of coordinates. I was wondering that I could separate the final result into 3 columns just like you see `x,` `y,` `z` in the picture above in my question.

Comment: Ah ok, see edit.

Comment: Your answer gives a little more addition to my learning. It also gives me a little bit clear idea of how to use subqueries. Thank you!